# How can I automatically start an Android device with the help of a timer when it turns off?

Tags: java, c#, android, adb, command-prompt

How can I automatically start an Android device with the help of a timer when it turns off? Is it possible? Can I do this with an adb command? Is there any other way? It will automatically turn back on when the Android device turns off??

I'm talking about completely shut down the Android device. The device is connected to power but the device is turned off. In this case I want the device to reboot automatically.

Can it be done with adb commands?

Or instead I'm thinking of detecting that the device is turned off and restarting it with remote access.

solved, thanks

Comment: By "turn off" you mean the display goes off or a complete device shutdown?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm talking about completely shut down the Android device. The device is connected to power but the device is turned off. In this case I want the device to reboot automatically.

Comment: Or instead I'm thinking of detecting that the device is turned off and restarting it with remote access.

Comment: If the device is off then no software is running on it, so how can you expect to connect via adb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that not possible
If your device supports this feature, you can usually find it in the device's settings menu under the "System" or "Power" section. If your device does not have this feature built-in, there isn't a simple software-based solution to achieve automatic power-on functionality.

Comment: I understand, thank you. Now I'm looking for different solutions.